# for (Object object : list) [java] and index element

Tags: java, list, loops

Is there a way to get an element id of a list to get it later through `list.get(index)`

when using

```
for(Object obj: o)
```

construction

Only define a local var and manually incrementing it?
Anything simpler?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, `for-each` loop doesn't keep track of index. You can either use a regular indexed loop, or do something like this:

```
int idx = 0;
for (Object o : list) {
   ...
   idx++;
}
```

This is risky since `break`/`continue` will make `idx` goes out of sync, so do use this infrequently, and only when the body is simple and only a few lines long.

If the elements are distinct, [`List.indexOf`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) would also work, albeit at `O(N)`, and at that point you may want to consider a `Set` (unordered, but guaranteed distinct).

---

It should also be said that sometimes using a [`listIterator()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) also alleviates the need of an explicit index while iterating.

A `ListIterator` supports `add`, `set` and `remove` operations.

This is another clear advantage `List` has over arrays as far as iteration mechanism goes.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is No.

The best I can think of is to combine iteration and indexing as follows:

```
int idx = 0;
for (Iterator<Object> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); idx++) {
    Object o = it.next();
    // ...
}
```

This approach has the advantage that `break` and `continue` won't mess up the `idx` calculations.

On the other hand, if the `list` is an `ArrayList` and you want to keep track of the index, you are probably better just using a variation of

```
for (idx = 0; idx < list.size(); idx++) {
    Object o = list.get(idx);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is not worded very well, but from what I can tell you would like to find the position of a specific `Object` within a `List<Object>`, and then retrieve it later via that index?

First of all, if you know the `Object` you are looking for then you should not need to have to find it in the `List`, since you have it already.

That said, you could easily do something like this:

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  if (list.get(i).equals(myObject)) {
    index = i; 
    break;
  }
}
```

But I would take a second look at your application to determine whether this is really something that is necessary for you to do.

Comment: I simply need to save a position in the list in every object's field. o.setPosInList(currentIndexOfTheLoop)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
list.indexOf(o);
```

The documentation is [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

@Eugene I see you mention in a comment to another answer that you plan to store the index of an object (with in the object in question?), that is probably not a good idea, be very careful since an objects index can change.

Comment: my answer however is sensible. and more importantly provides a link to better educated himself and others. if someone with the rep can edit the question more sensible that would be great.

Comment: Justin, I was going to downvote your answer, but I won't :-) - But it is the worst possible solution to this problem, mainly because if you maintain an index variable, the time required to compute the position in the index would be O(1), just the time required to increment the variable. With your approach, the time is O(n), where "n" is the position of the element in the list.

Comment: Also it returns the first occurrence, so if you have duplicates in the list it will always return the index of the first object that equals the parameter.

Comment: @Ravi, of course, but the OP asked for a "simpler" way to do it, he is already aware of incrementing a variable.